# 2次元配列を分割したい

Tags: python, array

102×102の行列を17×17の行列に分割したいです。
102行列は行列の番号がふってあるので、
読み込んだときにDataframeから配列になおしました。
102行列を読み込むことはできましたが、分割はどのようにしたらいいでしょうか。
分割はsplitを使えばいいのですか？
よろしくお願いします。

行列を読み込むところまでのコードは以下のように書いています。

```
dfs=[]
for filename in filenames:
    #print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=0)
    #print(df)

    a_df = df.values
    print(a_df)
    print(a_df.shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

numpyのスライシングだけを使って行列を分割してみました。

```
def func1(arr, block_size, block_num):
    size = block_size * block_num
    result = []
    for row in range(0, size, block_size):
        block = []
        for col in range(0, size, block_size):
            block.append(arr[row:row+block_size, col:col+block_size])
        result.append(block)
    return result
```

内包表記を使うと

```
def func2(arr, block_size, block_num):
    size = block_size * block_num
    return [[arr[row:row+block_size,col:col+block_size] for col in range(0, size, block_size)]　for row in range(0, size, block_size)]
```

Google Colab で処理時間を測ると、func1 が 115µs、func2 が 107µsでした。np.split を使ったものは、470µsでした。

Answer (score 1):

`a_df` は NumPy array なので、[`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) を 2 段階で使ってブロック行列を作るように実装してみました。

サンプルコードです：

```
block_size = 6
block_num = 17
size = block_size * block_num
arr = np.array([[i * j for j in range(size)] for i in range(size)])
h_arr = np.split(arr, block_num, axis=0)
hv_arr = [np.split(elm, block_num, axis=1) for elm in h_arr]
```

`np.split` は NumPy array のリストを返します。そこでまずは縦方向に切ってから、それぞれの部品を縦方向に切ることで、NumPy array のリストのリストを作っています。

また、他の方法が本家 Stack Overflow への投稿 [Slice 2d array into smaller 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16856788/5989200) にまとまっているのも見つけましたので参考までにリンクします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。画像分割はやったことがあるんですが配列は、難しかったです。勉強になりました。